# css multiple first and last dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to dynamically style every first and last element in row via css or js.

```html
<div class"box">
<ui>
<li class"one"></li> 
<li class"two"></li> First
<li class"two"></li>
<li class"two"></li>
<li class"two"></li> Last
<li class"one"></li> First
<li class"one"></li>
<li class"one"></li>
<li class"one"></li>
<li class"one"></li>
<li class"one"></li>
<li class"one"></li>
<li class"one"></li> Last
<li class"two"></li> First
<li class"two"></li>
<li class"two"></li>
<li class"two"></li>
<li class"two"></li>
<li class"two"></li> Last
</ui>
```

.two:last-child selects only one and last element in ui, instead of multiple in a raw same issue with .two:last-of-type

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way you could try:

```js
var oneList = document.getElementById("bigList").querySelectorAll(".one"); 
oneList.forEach(function (item) {
    if (item.nextElementSibling) {
        var nextSibling = item.nextElementSibling;
        if (nextSibling.classList.contains("two")) {
            item.classList.add("bg-green");
        }
    }
});

var twoList = document.getElementById("bigList").querySelectorAll(".two"); 
twoList.forEach(function (item) {
    if (item.nextElementSibling) {
        var nextSibling = item.nextElementSibling;
        if (nextSibling.classList.contains("one")) {
            item.classList.add("bg-green");
        }
    }
});
```

```css
/* First */
.one + .two, .two + .one {
  background-color: red;
}

/* Last */
.bg-green, #bigList li:last-child {
  background-color: green;
}

/* No style on first child */
#bigList li:first-child{
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
    <div class="box">
        <ul id="bigList">
            <li class="one">1</li> 
            <li class="two">2</li> <!--First-->
            <li class="two">2</li>
            <li class="two">2</li>
            <li class="two">2</li> <!--Last-->
            <li class="one">1</li> <!--First-->
            <li class="one">1</li>
            <li class="one">1</li>
            <li class="one">1</li>
            <li class="one">1</li>
            <li class="one">1</li>
            <li class="one">1</li>
            <li class="one">1</li> <!--Last-->
            <li class="two">2</li> <!--First-->
            <li class="two">2</li>
            <li class="two">2</li>
            <li class="two">2</li>
            <li class="two">2</li>
            <li class="two">2</li> <!--Last-->
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: @Kinglish nice catch, I've edited it to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution with the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<head>
<title>Try jQuery Online</title>
<script 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" 
type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
var cls="one";
var len = $('ui li').length;
$("ui li").each(function(index){

if(cls!=$(this).attr("class")){
$(this).attr("style","background-color:red;");
if(index!=1){

$(this).prev().attr("style","background-color:red;");
}
cls=$(this).attr("class");
}

   if(index === (len - 1)){
$(this).attr("style","background-color:red;");
   }
});

});
</script>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>
<UI>
<li class="one">test</li>
<li class="two">First</li>
<li class="two">test</li>
<li class="two">test</li>
<li class="two">Last</li>
<li class="one">First</li>
<li class="one">test</li>
<li class="one">test</li>
<li class="one">test</li>
<li class="one">test</li>
<li class="one">test</li>
<li class="one">test</li>
<li class="one">Last</li>
<li class="two">First</li>
<li class="two">test</li>
<li class="two">test</li>
<li class="two">test</li>
<li class="two">test</li>
<li class="two">Last</li>
</ui>
```